# Troubles using Polymer shadow dom inside custom element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create a custom polymer element. It requires adding a new tag to a div-container.

Here is an example:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      someHandler: function() {
        var el = document.createElement('span');
        this.$.container.appendChild(el);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Howewer if I add this element to my layout twice and call `someHandler()` on the second element, it adds span to the first element. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: @Supersharp ok, deleted those tags

Comment: I think you should use `Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(el)` instead

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz Great! That did the trick! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. I added this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate nodes with JavaScript you must use Polymer's API. Here's what the [documentation page](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api) says:

> Note: All DOM manipulation must use this API, as opposed to DOM API directly on nodes.

In your code, to add a child node, you should write:

```
Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(el);
```

I think it's for performance reasons too but, as you see, it would also appear to be related to how Polymer somehow manages its nodes.